# Why are there so many non-programming questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is there a reason why there are so many non-programming (Linux/Unix-related mostly) questions on Stack Overflow? Also, why aren't they moved?

I often encounter these questions when looking for help with Unix/Linux-related questions. There are usually lots of upvotes on the original poster too. Why not ask on *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* or *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*, etc.?

Comment: Take a look at [all sites sorted by their age](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest): Ubuntu.SE and Unix.SE were created 2 years after SO, etc.

Comment: Methinks this would be a better topic where it was originally posted - migrating it here will decrease the possibility of engaging communities that could be ENCOURAGING people to post _there_, instead of on StackOverflow.

Comment: Why should there be programming questions? We've got [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MatthewRock Because the line between SO and Programmers is fuzzy at places and because many questions which would be on-topic on Programmers but are posted on SO are not migrated.

Comment: The truth is that there are animals on here that think that because shell scripting questions are on topic, then any question about any command itself is on topic.  Which isn't.  They're command line programs.  Animals.

Comment: There is actually a tag `hardware`.

Comment: @will - **Dante Hicks:** *Someone posted non-programming questions on on SO.* 
**Veronica Loughran:** *You're kidding.* 
**Dante Hicks:** *Bunch of savages on these internets.*

Comment: Wondering why he got deleted within few hours of posting a good question (according to votes) in meta..!

Comment: The real question is - why do we have such site fragmentation in the first place?

Comment: Waiting for csharp.se, php.se, java.se @Sobrique :)

Comment: I was meaning specifically - my area of interest is as a sysadmin. I do `perl`, some `shell`, `awk`, `sed` etc. Some of that's Stack Overflow, some is Unix and Linux, some is ServerFault. And I think we've got a DevOps SE in the pipe line too now, and Programmers etc. Stack Overflow does suffer from having a bit too much 'siloing' of completely separate tech stacks - more so that U&L does. Which would almost suggest a language-family based site _would_ be appropriate.

Comment: @TJ He posted on meta.se, it was migrated here, but he doesn't have an account here (or on SO) yet.

Comment: @Will Ah I see. He will still get notified of the answers right..?

Comment: @TJ nope.  No grey account does.... Whoops, he does have one on SO.  Hmm, thought it was automatically created on the child meta. Oh well.

Comment: I'm just appreciating the irony in that this question was moved from a different META SO...

Comment: Why there are so many stupid people in this world?

Comment: Tell me what "non-programming" means. Then we can talk about an answer. Programming is an incredibly *vast* field. Software is typically layered on top of multiple layers of other software, which is layered on top of hardware. Sometimes you need to work with the underlying stuff to make your code behave the way you want (especially true of the operating system), so those types of questions are most certainly *relevant* to programming. So again, define "non-programming".

Comment: @jpmc26 I provided some links below. questions that relate to find command or bash and many other linux commands that has nothing to do programming normally unless context is provided of course. :) There are obvious commands that are programming related like git.

Comment: @mrjayviper An argument could be made that writing commands in bash or Command Prompt is fundamentally programming, and that no distinction is actually useful.

Comment: @jpmc26 not necessarily. what if it's about how to start the bittorrent client daemon  in FreeBSD/Linux because it's "fundamentally programming"? How about converting PNG images to jpg via commandline? why can't we draw a line where obvious linux only commands that has no programming related context be moved to other parts of SE?

Comment: @mrjayviper All of those things could be something someone wants to script. Wouldn't that be programming? What's the difference from asking how to do them in a bash script vs. asking how to do them in Python or Ruby? Or are you really saying we should ask the asker whether or not they intend to put the command in a script and then discriminate based on that? Seems impractical.

Answer (score 53):

> Why are there are so many non-programming questions in Stack Overflow?

In general, because we don't do a good enough job of discouraging them. Every time an off-topic question is upvoted or answered, we do the exact opposite. With that encouragement, we are inviting more off-topic questions.

> I often encounter these questions when looking for help with unix/linux related questions.

Unix/Linux is a special case, as [Patrick describes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315557/1677912). The same grand-fathering exists with other topics that now have SE sites; Programmers, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (stats), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)...

Heck, pretty much everything on the [Technology list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) is represented with questions that were posted on StackOverflow before the topic-specific site existed. But I believe your question is really *Why are we seeing so many NEW questions that belong on other Stack Exchange communities?*

I believe it is an outcome of the [Broken Windows theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory): as long as we *have* such off-topic questions, they appear to be the norm.

The solution is hard.

1. Stop breaking windows: Aggressively migrate every new off-topic question to the appropriate community.

- This may require technology help to identify these questions ASAP, which will need resources from Stack Overflow, inc. If the "off-topic" close dialog made it easier to identify and select target communities, that would help with funnelling questions in the right direction.
- Without technical help, it just doesn't scale.
- I've seen a comment lately (ref?) that SO is so big that it can drown smaller sites (presumably with migrations). If that's the case, then... good? I mean, if a question posted on Stack Overflow belongs on another site, then how is migrating it there any different, from a load standpoint, than having it posted there in the first place?

2. Fix the windows: As long as we view old off-topic questions as golden treasures, newcomers will take them as examples of community standards. So, the solution is to aggressively (there's that word again) indicate that those questions are NOT a standard. Every old off-topic question must be:

- Closed and deleted, or
- Edited to be on-topic, with off-topic answers deleted or edited, or
- Migrated to a newly-appropriate site in the network, despite the 60-day limit, or
- at the very least, marked clearly as not meeting current standards.

Comment: There's also the pesky phrase "software tools commonly used by programmers" in the description of what's ["on topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Absent any clear description of what a software "tool" actually *is*, that opens the door to almost anything that runs on a computer. ("Hey, some programmers use Linux so my 'Linux question' must be on-topic.")

Comment: Not that I'm advocating any solution, but there is a third option to be complete: stop the forced segregation of topic over multiple websites. Why bother with forcing a split if the community seems to not want it ?  I'll repeat: not advocating it, just for completeness.

Comment: @GordThompson: Well, but that's filtered by "; and is •a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". A general run-of-the-mill Linux question is unlikely to actually be a software development question.

Comment: @GordThompson Good point, and right in line with the whole Technology set of sites... ALL those things appear on-topic, according to the guidelines we publish. We don't say "...unless another more specific site would be appropriate", or anything to encourage critical thought about where the question belongs. As long as help is quickly available on Stack Overflow, we'll keep seeing off-topic questions.

Comment: @swa66 Actually, that's mostly the transients, and it's not that they don't *want* it for the most part, it's that they are oblivious and don't care anyway.

Comment: The problem of SO questions drowning smaller sites is not the amount of content: it's the fact that most migrated questions are poor ones or are off-topic for the target site. e.g. lots of Android programming questions get migrated to android.SE, which is not for programmers. The result is that every site gets a review backlog as unmanageable as SO's, but with far fewer users who can access review queues.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks for that clarification - like I said, a hard problem. In many cases, simply redirecting the _user_ to another site would mitigate that load, but partly due to unhappy, unhelped users.

Comment: There's also the issue of people having different opinions of what's "on-topic".

Comment: Deleting grandfathered questions prevents the information from being consumed by later users.  Adding something which indicates that the question is now off topic with a link to the site where it should be (similar to the duplicate question system) is a better solution.

Comment: @Trisped I assure you that most off-topic popular question have been reasked on another site

Comment: @Braiam My experience is the opposite.  There is also the issue that not all of them have been asked on the correct site, so you are losing valuable information and the fact that, though duplicates, the answers will be different and may provide value.

Comment: I'd tend to agree but before we start to fix _this_ windows I would seriously try to fix the _other broken windows_: terribly low quality questions (and dump of requirements, bla bla bla). I find they are much more annoying than slightly off-topic ones. Nowadays I often give up to answer something just because I have to browse four pages of terrible questions (maybe finally even answering another just less terrible one).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti usually, they are not mutually exclusive ;)

Comment: @Braiam true, I was just...ranting! ;)

Comment: Neither #1 nor #2 will happen as long as rep comes from answering bad questions rather than closing/migrating/etc. them.

Answer (score 44):

In the old days, there were only a few sites (the trilogy). Possibly those questions are from the time the rules were flexible on the subject, since there was no alternative.

Nowadays, with a lot of sites in the community, it is much easier to pick a site to migrate to, and that is usually done.

Moving an established question to another site in the network is actually never done. (The close dialog even says the post is 'too old to migrate' after 60 days.)

Comment: *after some time* is 60 days: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156894/158100

Comment: I don't think this is limited to questions from a long time ago. I remember seeing several recent questions. For example, I flagged [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365885/can-maldet-scan-across-mounted-filesystems) from December 2015 as off topic. The flag was disputed and the question is still there with a net +1 vote (after my downvote).

Comment: How come "established" questions are never moved?  Why are they exempt?

Comment: @Blackwood and you were so nice to not even leave a comment as to why you downvoted him. That'll teach him! (for the record: Neither did the other 2 who downvoted that question.)

Comment: @Blackwood definitely not. I posted 2 links below and already with up-votes (minus my downvote). While I appreciate the help it gives me (I was seeking help when I found the discussion), I certainly think there are more appropriate SE sites for them.

Comment: @Blackwood I agree the question you mention should be closed, and it is now. In this case, the community failed to do the right thing. Sometimes it happens... Especially when there are not a lot of active users in the tags on the question. I have seen questions on my main tag close within 25 seconds :) .

Comment: @brandaemon Good question. I don't know actually, but it seems that if the community fails to do the right thing in time, the question is locked on that site. That will prevent reputation to get lost for example. And it might prevent questions from years ago to me migrated, which might be what SE wanted.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Is it possible that SE networks could support the feature of transferring reputation to the appropriate site along with the question and answers when they need to be moved?

Comment: That would be bad for several reasons.

Comment: Migrating a question *and* granting the same user the same reputation in the new site (after removing it from the source site) would not be bad, and would allow this feature to be not locked anymore.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why would that be bad?  Does SE want to keep off-topic questions on sites for any reason, even if they're old or popular?  As discussed elsewhere on this question, such a policy encourages new users to ask off-topic questions because they'll think it's okay when they see the legacy questions.

Answer (score 27):

I don’t know which specific questions you are referring to, and there are certainly some that are actually off topic.

But in general most of these questions *are on topic* and should remain here: Note that the criterion doesn’t say “are about programming” but “are programming related”:

> […] if your question generally covers
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

[From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)]

Many aspects of (say) Git and Linux *are* intimately related to programming. Sure, for some things the Unix&Linux site is a better forum, but many are just fine here on Stack Overflow.

In general, off topic questions are quite seriously policed here — I don’t feel that moderation is lacking in this particular aspect.

Comment: The exact quote from the on-topic page is: "; and is •a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development."

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, and I think this is a pretty good criterion (although “unique” is also debatable — in principle, for instance, we can use Git for non-programming things; in practice, it’s mainly used for programming). I’ve added this to my answer.

Comment: Random example of the day (for some reason the 4th or 5th *blatantly* off-topic q. I encountered this hour): do [red and blue glasses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35047879/2564301) fall under "tools commonly used by programmers"?

Comment: @Jongware: Maybe, for some value of "common". But they certainly fail the second part of the test.

Comment: @Jongware I’m not sure this is the kind of question OP had in mind: it’s already deleted, and there was never any chance of it staying on. Which is my point exactly: Stack Overflow is already policed (zealously!) for off topic questions. Since OP didn’t give any examples we’re arguing a bit in the void here but I suspect that most questions OP dislikes are actually *perfectly* on topic and should remain here.

Comment: Exactly Konrad! As an early beta tester for SO, I thoroughly enjoy both types of questions and their answers. Maybe this current trend of the roaming gangs going around stomping on any programming question that does not have a "correct/wrong" answer will disappear like the self-appointed "Amazon Police". They suddenly started stomping on me for putting Amazon links in my answers even though any Amazon Associates data was removed leaving just the Amazon reference id '/dp/nnnnnnnnn/'. Maybe Clay Shirky was right <http://goo.gl/vXB7vC>, and this is a normal cycle for online communities... :-)

Comment: do you think this is on-topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982894/eliminating-subfolders-to-move-all-files-into-one-folder

Comment: how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797696/how-to-find-files-with-same-size-possible-duplicates-in-a-directory-and-its-su

Comment: both links I mentioned above has up-votes. and the poster didn't even bother to provide a programming related context

Comment: Rob Wells - -couldn't agree more with your sentiments. i often bemoan how homoginized SO has become due to zealous over policing (by what feels like 12 year olds). oh well, guess i need to get with the gang.. lol

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answers already here, [Stack Overflow is the most popular Stack Exchange site by several metrics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265787/which-stack-exchange-site-is-the-most-popular). It really has the most "brand recognition" if you will, and thus attracts a lot of beginners and outsiders.

When Average Joe who doesn't frequent SE sites and isn't that involved has a technical question that would probably be better suited for one of the other sites, he just thinks "Oh, I'll ask it on SO" because it always gets high marks on Google searches, because it's kind of the grandfather of SE sites. Joe would not even think about the other sites, or know they exist.

On top of that, how would he know if his question is better suited for Stack Overflow, Programmers, Code Review, Server Fault, Linux & Unix, Ask Ubuntu, or Super User?  He would have to do research, and that's too much work! (admittedly, I am guilty of this sometimes too) And the people who do do their research are probably going to answer that duplicate or off-topic question themselves anyways, so they're weeded out.

Plus sometimes, programming and server administration kind of bleed together, so there's kind of a gray area in the middle somewhere.

That's my take anyways, and is a pretty common theme among these off-topic or duplicate questions I see on SO.

Comment: If I were a Stack Overflow site owner or employee, and the income depended on how many visits the site gets, I would not care one little bit how many "off-topic" questions there are.  If income plummeted from off topic questions, then either something would happen very quickly, or management are idiots.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head here. Stack Overflow is a popular site where people ask lots of questions and they get answered, so people assume if they have a question they can ask and it will be answered too. They don't put any thought into whether it's an appropriate forum or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that there are many questions that have a large grey area with regards to either programming or other computer related topics.  I am seeing some of questions that could fit on both https://stackoverflow.com/ and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

It might also be due to the fact that StackOverflow has the largest community and therefore, would have more people that could possibly answer the question.

Comment: Large community doesn't automatically mean more eyes looking at each question. For example, my latest question on SO got only 14 views in 40 hours (and 3 of those views are probably myself from different computers). This never happened to me on other SE sites, even on tiny ones like RPi.

Answer (score -21):

Because the answers help us decide our architecture, programming methodology and strategy.

Comment: A "just because" answer :) Example needed

Comment: Those things belong on programmers.stackexchange.com, in particular: "software architecture and design" and "development methodologies and processes" are [on topic there](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."